# Memoir class -- Displayed heading for subsubsection

Tags: memoir, sectioning, titlesec

I am trying to make a subsection heading with the memoir class.
The problem is the following:

I want to have a displayed heading for my subsubsection. The text should begin right after the subsubsec heading as a new line, and NOT as a new paragraph.

Memoir sets as a vertikal space after the headings the lenghts
`afterskip + \parskip(of heading font) + \baselineskip(of text font)`.
To solve the problem, it would be plausible to set afterskip to -parskip. But, if afterskip becomes a negative value, the heading will turn into a run-in style.

I made my tests with the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\parskip9pt
\parindent0pt

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setbeforesubsubsecskip{9pt}
\setaftersubsubsecskip{1pt}

\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\scshape}
\begin{document}

\subsubsection{lorem ipsum}
lorem ipsum

lorem ipsum 
\end{document}
```

I used before the titlesec package, and it was excelent, till I not tried to use \titleref... This \titleref doesn't work with this package only for the chapters. If I dont't use titlesec, the references for sections working also good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a temp fix

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@startsection}[6]{%
  \@nameuse{#1block}%
  \ifraggedbottomsection\if@nobreak\else
    \vskip\z@\@plus\bottomsectionskip
    \penalty\z@
    \vskip\z@\@plus -\bottomsectionskip
  \fi\fi
  \def\m@msecn@me{#1}%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \par
  \@tempskipa #4\relax
  \@afterindenttrue
  \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@
    \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
  \fi
  \if@nobreak
    \everypar{}%
  \else
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty%
    \addvspace\@tempskipa
    \addvspace{-\parskip}% <--- added
  \fi
  \@ifstar
    {\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
    {\@trplargoom{\M@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}}

\def\@xsect#1{%
  \@tempskipa #1\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
  \par
  \nobreak
  \vskip \@tempskipa
  \vskip-\parskip% <--- added
  \@afterheading
  \else
  \@nobreakfalse
  \global\@noskipsectrue
  \everypar{%
    \if@noskipsec
     \global\@noskipsecfalse
     {\setbox\z@\lastbox}%
     \clubpenalty\@M
     \begingroup \@svsechd \endgroup
     \unskip
     \@tempskipa #1\relax
     \hskip -\@tempskipa
     \else
    \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
    \everypar{}%
     \fi}%
   \fi
  \ignorespaces}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 2):

I've just removed the \parskip influence on the chapter spacings, might be an idea to also introduce this inside sectional constructions

One reason why this has not already been done is that for the most part, documents with no parindent and non-zero parskip are not particularly good for communication, especially if the document has many lists or displayed math.

Comment: Pardon? I don't really understand you :-)

Comment: I maintain the memoir class

Comment: how does one remove a comment?

Comment: So you will make in the next time an update without parksip influence? If yes, when do you want to do it?

Comment: I usually release on sundays. So if I do not have other pressing issues, it should be able to make it for the coming sunday.

One problem of course is that it will change existing documents with non-zero parskip.

Comment: I usually know may way round memoir.

BTW: here is a better method of setting the spacing below to a near zero value

    `\setaftersubsubsecskip{1sp}`

sp is the smallest unit in TeX, AFAIK about the wave length of visible light

Comment: @daleif Welcome to tex.sx!  It's good to see some more c.t.t. people here as well.

Comment: @alan  Thanks, I have to admit I'm mostly here to look for people with memoir problems as apparently they never make it to ctt.

Comment: @daleif That's fine; your help will be much appreciated. The sx model is quite interesting, though.